# Session handling between Laravel and Vue for a shopping cart

Tags: laravel, vue.js, session, cookies, axios

I have a Laravel Vue application. The goal is to build a shop. Frontend and backend run on the same server. I don't use any authentication (so no registration etc.). Nevertheless I want to start a session for the user as soon as he comes to the website. So that the shopping cart of the respective user remains saved.

The workflow is roughly clear to me. I haven't really found anything specifically for this case. But I think that it is not only me. That's why I'm asking you. Could you please outline the process here. I use POST, GET, PUT and DELETE methods for manipulating the shopping basket.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use vuex for the front end state and then just send the data to the backend when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i got your question right or not but in my case  if i worked on shopping cart i have two method to save data the first one is to use vuex to store data but if i need this data to be exist if i refresh the browser i will use localStorage as it's exist for purpose like this or  i will use reddis and each time the user add something to cart i will add it to reddis and when he remove it i will remove it from it